How to use accessibilitydatasensitive in jetpack compose
How can we set accessibilitydatasensitive flag to yes in compose?

You can use this feature by using semantic on Modifier for composables
study this article on android documents : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/accessibility#semantics
also if you wanted to use xml you would be able to use below code:
<textview accessibilitydatasensitive="yes" android:text="Your PIN number is 1234"> 


I know how to set it in xml my question is about compose. The article you shared doesn't have anything related to that flag!

You don't need to set it when you are using Compose
modifier.semantic is what that flag actually does on XML
